# Downloading images from Parse

Tags: image, parse-platform, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am working on a project that uses a parse server. It works like tinder and allows users to download and display names and images of other users nearby.

It works, accept for one bug where the names and the images do not match up correctly when displayed in the app.

The app initially downloads and creates an array of local users, and this works fine.

I then download their images using the following code:

```
 ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereWithinKilometers("location", parseCustLocation, searchRadius);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {


            @Override
            public void done(final List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e==null){
                    Log.d("state", "215 query successful");
                    if (objects.size()>0) {
                        for (final ParseUser user : objects){
                            Log.d("state", "231"+user.getUsername());
                            //TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Name);

                            Users.add(user);
                            sUsers.add((String) user.get("Name"));
                            locations.add((ParseGeoPoint) user.get("location"));
                            parseFiles.add((ParseFile) user.get("image"));
                          }

                for (ParseFile file : parseFiles) {
                        file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {


                            @Override
                            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                if (e==null){
                                    Log.d("state", "174 we've got data");
                                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
                                    bitmaps.add(bmp);

                                    if (sUsers.size()==bitmaps.size()){
                                        swipeAdapter.updateData(sUsers,bitmaps);
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        });}
```

As far as I can tell, I think the issue is with the lines

```
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
    bitmaps.add(bmp);
```

as, for example, when I run the debugger I have two arrays as follows (the bitmapFactory seems to be putting the bitmaps in any part of the bitmap[]):

```
sUsers[0] = "Billy",   
sUsers[1] = "Sarah",   
sUsers[2] = "Jim",  

bitmaps[0] = Sarahs image,   
bitmaps[1] = Jims image,   
bitmaps[2] = Billys image
```

When obviously I need

```
bitmaps[0] = Billys image,   
bitmaps[1] = Sarahs image,   
bitmaps[2] = Jims image,
```

NOTE:
The bitmaps seem to be in the correct order if I run the app step by step using the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

file.getDataInBackground is an async callback, so the first data retrieved will be the first added to bitmaps array,

You can use an Hashmap each key will be the user objectId and the key the data of your user.

```
Map<String, data> map = new HashMap<String, data>(); // your Hashmap
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Julien, I managed to get it working correctly but with a very crude workaround using lots of nested Async tasks:

```
 parseFiles.get(0).getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                            if (e==null){


                                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                                bitmaps.add(0, bmp);

                                parseFiles.get(1).getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                        if (e==null){


                                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                                            bitmaps.add(1, bmp);

                                            parseFiles.get(2).getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                                    if (e==null){

                                                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                                                        bitmaps.add(2, bmp);
                                                        parseFiles.get(3).getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                                                if (e==null){

                                                               Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                                                                bitmaps.add(3, bmp);

                                                                    parseFiles.get(4).getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                                                            if (e==null){
                                                                                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                                                                               bitmaps.add(4, bmp);

                                                                              parseFiles.get(5).getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                                                                                    @Override
                                                                                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                                                                        if (e==null){

                                                                                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                                                                                            //bitmaps.add(bmp);

                                                                                            bitmaps.add(5, bmp);


                                                                                            if (sVenueUsers.size()==bitmaps.size()){
                                                                                                swipeAdapter.updateData(sUsers, bitmaps);
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                });


                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    });


                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        });

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });

                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }
                    });
```

I tried your Hashmap idea, but got the message that data was an unrecognised class. I shall try working it through later.